# Using mysql function in spago BI

Tags: spagobi

Could any one please tell me to use call mysql function while creating spago data mart.
I have created data mart and calling mysql function "find_circle" from calculated field but it is giving error

```
find_circle(Partner id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by making sql view and executed that function inside that view and linked that view while creating DataMart.

Thanks,